# If a value then return all column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

so I have a similar table like this:

| Employee ID | Name | Function | Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2324 | Bruno | Unpaid Student | D |
| 4378 | John | Operator | B |
| 1218 | Barack | Operator | B |

What I want to is to apply a formula where: if the person is an "Operator" or "Unpaid Student" then return me the whole line and all inputs. Because I am going to create one sheet for each function. So, my desired output will be:

(Unpaid Student Sheet)

| Employee ID | Name | Function | Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2324 | Bruno | Unpaid Student | D |

(Operator Sheet)

| Employee ID | Name | Function | Level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4378 | John | Operator | B |
| 1218 | Barack | Operator | B |

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Does your version of Excel support FILTER?

Comment: Yes, my version supports it!

Comment: Then there is your answer =). Let us know if you can't work it out using `FILTER()`.

Comment: And MID+CELL with FIND+CELL will return information about the current sheet that would allow you to set up the formula completely dynamically.  Copy the sheet, change the name to the right category and it automatically populates.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! The only question I have rn is: When I try to add the formula inside my table it gives me the  "#SPILL! " error but it works when I insert outside the table. Is there anyway I can directly insert inside my table (which has no data and only the headers) instead of having to add it outside the table and then having to create a table?

Comment: @BrunoTavares, don't create a table, just use the headers and use `FILTER()` right below the headers in the left topmost cell. Otherwise it will try to spill the results in each row of your table which will lead to your current error.

Comment: Yeah I just figured out that when I used this filter formula it gives me the information as a new table. The only problem is that I have other columns on the right side (not only the output of applying the formula), where my employees are going to complete it with manual information and I would like to have all if it were a table. Do you know if is the possible? Not sure if I explained myself

Comment: If the manual input will be in the source column then extend the range of your Filter formula, for example in cell G2 = Filter(A2:E6, C2:C6="Unpaid Student"), where column E is where employees do the manual input.

Answer (score 0):

I would apply the formula in the main sheet and use Pivot Table in different sheets to filter. This way I don't have to worry about broken formulas in 2 different sheets.